# How to include Cordova.js in HTML5

Tags: javascript, cordova, phaser-framework

I would like to convert my HTML5 game to iOS/Android app, I can do it using Phonegap or Cocoon, all tutorials show that we must include cordova.js file into index.html page.

If I include cordova.js as suggested:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="js/phaser.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/game.js"></script>
</head>
</html>
```

I can see this message:

```
_Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at cordova.js:28_
```

Also, I have uploaded a project to web server and I get same results. Downloaded cordova from here
https://github.com/apache/cordova-js/blob/master/src/cordova.js

[image]

Comment: This might be dumb question... but did you tried running cordova only without phaser? I "think" you need another file called require maybe? Look under Project Structure in this link: https://github.com/apache/cordova-js
  
I'm guessing it's a node module called "require"

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you just copied the cordova.js file straight from GitHub and included it in your project manually.

If you want to use Cordova you should instead be using Node.js to create your project and define your platforms. This in turn will include the full cordova.js file, which includes the `require()` function.

[Create your first Cordova app](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/) on the official site includes a basic tutorial on getting started, and GameDev Academy has a tutorial on [Creating Mobile Games with Phaser 3 and Cordova](https://gamedevacademy.org/creating-mobile-games-with-phaser-3-and-cordova/).

Essentially, once you have Cordova tools and requirements installed:

1. `cordova create projectName` to create the new project.
2. `cd projectName` to move into the new project directory.
3. `cordova platform add android` and/or whatever platforms you want your game to run on.
4. Update the **www** directory as you normally would for a Phaser game. You can follow the GameDev Academy tutorial and use Node.js to install Phaser, or just copy/paste the JS file, whichever you're more comfortable with.
5. `cordova build` to make sure everything builds.
6. `cordova emulate android` to test it in Android, for example, but change as needed for your particular environments.

Comment: Thanks,so if I already have a complete Phaser game, I should create new cordova project and put game files into it? I am confused because tutorial shows how to build the game but it starts with creating cordova project then building the game. So, I already finished Phaser game, now just need to "include" cordova

Comment: Since you already have the game created without Cordova, that's what I would recommend doing, yes. On the bright side it's relatively easy to do so.